# Apache zeppelin - scope of the variable with angular and zeppelin interpreter

Tags: angularjs, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I'm playing with this tutorial

https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin/pull/27#issuecomment-90769401

It seems the scope of the val **selectedTable** is reachable from %%angular interpreter but not from zeppelin interpreter.

For instance, from the paragraph 2 of the turorial

```
{
val stat = sqlContext.sql("select count(*) as cnt, min(balance), cast(avg(balance) as INT), max(balance) from " + z.angular("selectedTable")).collect

val count = stat(0)(0)
val minBalance = stat(0)(1)
val maxBalance = stat(0)(2)
val avgBalance = stat(0)(3)

print(s"""%angular
<h2>Table {{selectedTable}}</h2>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"><center><h3>$count</h3>Total customers</center></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><center><h3>$minBalance</h3>Minimum balance</center></div>
</div>
<br />
<div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><center><h3>$maxBalance</h3>Average balance</center></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><center><h3>$avgBalance</h3>Maximum balance</center></div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

""")
```

}

when I use the select and I switch the value from "bank" to "married" the value of **{{selectedTable}}** (%%angula interpreter that printed the title) changed immediately (without click ion the play button except the first time) but the query is not running. In other words no data is loaded into the charts.

While if you look the video at this url https://youtu.be/QdjZyOkcG_w?t=15 you can see that every time the select has a different value all the queries are executed one by one.

Does anyone have the same issue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you get a chance to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue where references to **{{selectedTable}}** updated immediately but none of the notebook cells ran automatically.  I was able to correct the issue by altering the **z.run()** values in the z.angularWatch() function.

**z.run()** refreshes/runs the contents of whatever cell is referenced, so z.run(0) runs the first cell, and so on.  The default z.run(2[3,4], selectedTableContext) should be updated to match the correct cells in your notebook.

Comment: is there a way to run cells by name rather than by index?

Comment: This is an old post but there is a paragraph id which can be obtained at the top right 'settings' icon of the paragraph. So you can do a z.run('paragraph_1234_12233'), where 'paragraph_1234_12233' is an example of paragraph id. I am using Zeppelin 0.9.0-preview1 but I think this is available for prior versions too.